# I've got a large Groovy application (~2000 lines) using multiple .groovy files. How should I handle the generated class files?

Tags: class, groovy

When the application is completely self contained within one .groovy file there are no .class files generated.  However, when I separate out the classes into separate files and place them in packages, I end up with hundreds of generated .class files (most are from all of the closures compiling to bytecode separately).

What is the best approach for managing the file system when all of these files are generated and end up cluttering the folder?

1. Should I leave everything in one file? That's the cleanest approach
   to the file system but I end up with a large .groovy file and no
   separation of logic.
2. Should I package everything into a jar? That
   would work but it cuts down on the flexibility of having a script
   run directly with small changes as necessary.
3. Do I just ignore the .class files?

Comment: You should keep the logic's separation, and create a "/target" folder w/ your build tool (gradle or whatever) to gather the generated classes inside that normalized folder.

Comment: I've been considering building with gradle but it adds a step into the workflow considering a .groovy file can just be executed directly.  I guess I can't have it both ways (flexible execution directly from text and clean deployment).  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I agree, i think clean deployment is much more flexible and reliable on the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #2 is best, provided you use a build tool like [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). Our DevOps team uses Groovy, and delivers self-contained zip files.

As an simple example, look at [this project](https://github.com/peidevs/WarO_Groovy).

It delivers `warO.zip`, which unzips to:

```
warO.jar
jars/groovy-all-1.6.4.jar
jars/guava-collections-r03.jar
jars/guava-base-r03.jar
```

Because the manifest is set with main class and classpath, the user can then execute with:

`java -jar warO.jar`

Your user audience will love it. They don't even need Groovy installed, just the JRE.

Regarding the dev cycle, it is true that edits to the script are not quite as fast, but by adding Gradle tasks (or simple scripts), it is easy to automate the steps to build, deploy locally, and execute.

Comment: thank you for this.  I've actually proceeded with a gradle approach and it's working nicely in creating an uber jar.  Here's the project if you're curious https://github.com/garypaduana/Scripts/tree/master/General%20File%20Utility

Still very much a work in progress as I'm transitioning to github from a local svn repo.

Answer (score 1):

Building an executable jar with your scripts and embedded Groovy is simple with [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org).

The advantage is verification that the scripts are compilable and unit tested before deployment to a production environment.

Here's an example:

**scripts/src/main/groovy/script1.groovy**

```
println "Hello World!"

def aTestableMethod() {
    1 + 1
}
```

---

**scripts/src/test/groovy/script1Test.groovy**

```
import org.junit.Test
import static org.junit.Assert.*

class Script1Test {
    @Test
    public void checkATestableMethod() {
        def script1 = new script1()
        assertEquals 2, script1.aTestableMethod()
    }
}
```

---

**scripts/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'script1'
    }
}
```

---

To build and execute:

```
$ gradle build
$ java -jar build/libs/scripts/scripts.jar
Hello World!
```

---

The [Groovy Environment Manager (GVM)](http://gvmtool.net) makes it easy to install and manage Groovy and related tools including [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org).

Comment: This does not include my source code (i.e. src/org....). I have tried so many different build.gradle configurations and seem to be missing something basic (I used to be a .Net developer). So in summary it does all my depenedencies and meta stuff perfectly but leaves out the actual code, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you compile the .groovy file, you would get the same .class files.

That out of the way, I want to mention an alternative, but I don't advise using that.

Groovy is very well able to compile dependent .groovy files at runtime. The first requirement is that the files follow the java conventions for packages. For example if you have the class Foo in package bar in a .groovy file the file must be in ./bar/Foo.groovy and the root directory "." must be on the classpath.

The second requirement is that Groovy must be able to clearly recognize the class as class and that it cannot be a property. So for example "def a = Foo.class" alone, is not clear, since Foo could be a property. A "import bar.Foo" makes things clear. Same for usage of the class in class-, interface-, field- or method-headers, as well as in catch clauses and new-instance expressions.

The third requirement is that a GroovyClassLoader is used for looking up the class.

If you use the groovy command from the command line, then this is the case. The groovy command will put the current directory on the classpath as well.

Comment: I started with this approach yesterday but then changed to using gradle and everything is working nicely as expected with jar output. Thanks for the input!